# How to copy directories/files in installed folder using wix

Tags: wix

I have deployment files which are dynamic in nature. Sometimes I have 4 files and sometimes 5 files. I need to just copy those files in installed folder.

1. How to include those files in msi?
2. How to copy it in installed folder?

Comment: Please provide some more information in your question. At the moment it's unlikely you will receive any answers as it's not clear what the problem is. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 0):

You include files in your msi by harvesting them with wix tool [harvest tool set](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/heat.html)

Once you have proper msi file , you install it and that will copy your harvested files to the desired dir.

Comment: I have already done harvesting which generating src.wxs file. But I installed it, it's not copying files in installed directory....

Comment: make a verbal output into your log file and check ur custom actions for errors ( also anywhere it returns 3  something failed).